url luncher for flutter
iam trying to add flutter url luncher dependencies but i gat this
Launching lib\main.dart on 23021RAAEG in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\android.jar.
> C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\android.jar


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
cant add flutter url luncher

Does this answer your question? Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:parseDebugLocalResources

.Open project in Android Studio
Go to SDK manager(Android Studio > SDK Manager > SDK Platforms) and uninstall and then install again Android sdk.
. check build.grade for minSdkVersion
. check AndroidManifest.xml file for permmissons
<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your application checks for inAppBrowserView launch mode support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
  </intent>
</queries>

then run
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter run --release

